# Не берет 100% от родительского div

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поместить картину в `div` и взять 100% от высоты родительского `div`?

```css
.rod {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.name {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: url(https://propozitsiya.com/sites/default/files/styles/580x/public/news/kava.jpg?itok=E059m3Wm) no-repeat center;
}
```

```html
<div class="rod">
  <div class="name"><span style='float:left;'>Кофе</span><span style='float:right;'>20 ₴</span></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: может стили лучше вынести отдельно?  это ж не читабельно.

Comment: @СергейПетрашко готово

Answer (score 0):

Тут однозначного ответа не будет, скорее всего. Тут проблема с высотами блоков. 
тебе или ставить в `px`. Вместо процентов нужно или делать `.image` - `position:absolute` - и подгонять.

[Статья](https://learn.javascript.ru/height-percent) на  эту тему.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала добавьте `html,body` свойство `height: 100%`, иначе не понятно от чего блоку `rod` брать `50%` высоты. Этот вариант исправит проблему в вашем примере. Но, не зная какой результат нужен сложно подобрать более правильный вариант.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.rod {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.name {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: url(https://propozitsiya.com/sites/default/files/styles/580x/public/news/kava.jpg?itok=E059m3Wm) no-repeat center;
}
```

```html
<div class="rod">
  <div class="name"><span style='float:left;'>Кофе</span><span style='float:right;'>20 ₴</span></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```